# In XSLT adding an element to a copy gets added multiple times. Why?

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the following situation. Given: XML and XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="info">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:element name="foo">
                <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <info>
        <somthing>lorem ipsum</somthing>
    </info>
</root>
```

When transforming the XML with the given XSLT template, I get this result

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <info>
    <somthing>lorem ipsum</somthing>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <foo>bar</foo> <!-- too much -->
    <foo>bar</foo> <!-- too much -->
  </info>
</root>
```

It should identity copy the XML document and append `<foo>bar</foo>` to the `<info>` element, but it adds two aditional `<foo>`s. I tried a lot, but cannot figure out why it does this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7nh. How are you testing this?

Comment: I was running this in Eclipse Webttools XML development tool (Mars, up to date)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete the tag xsl:apply-templates from inside the 2nd template?

```
<xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="foo">
            <xsl:text>bar</xsl:text>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to a question. (Yes, but then the children of `<info>` don't get copied. Not what  I want.)